# How to show zooming bar in google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using the following google map and everything looks perfect:

[Google map](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-clustering.html)

The only problem is that when a person zoom in to the street level and wants to zoom out he needs to have a mouse and use mouse wheel and if he does not have mouse working with this map is a pain.

So I need to put zooming bar  for example at left side of my map like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do that and how can I do that?(I appreciate any help)

Comment: The link to your google map is NOT google-maps-api-3.

Comment: Thanks for your comment do you think there is a way to do that?

Comment: Your are using the deprecated and turned off [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference). New development with that version of the API is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the control to your map, like this:

```
map.addControl(new GSmallZoomControl());
```

You can find more information about GMaps controls here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/controls

This quote is from the above mentioned documentation

> GSmallZoomControl - a small zoom control (no panning controls) used in the small map blowup windows used to display driving directions steps on Google Maps.

Comment: Your recommendation is using the [deprecated and turned off Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference).  Using that version of the API is not recommended.

Comment: Yes, i know, but the OP asked about google-maps-api-2, so i had no choice, i guess.

Comment: @ newboyhun thanks for your reply though I did not solve my issue in that way your answer gave me good starting point for searching